# PHP inheritance weird use of $this operator

Tags: php, inheritance, this, extends

I have one little question. On PHP manual site there is one example:

```
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
            // Foo::testPublic
```

Can anybody explain in a simple way why reference $this in one example points to parent method (private method) and in another to current method defined in a child class (public)?
It s not logical for me, i would expect it to point to child class methods in **both** cases or to parent methods in both cases?

Please help!

Comment: you didn't paste the second example I guess

Comment: because `testPrivate` is overridden in child class and `$myFoo` object does not access to `testPrivate` in `Bar` class.

Comment: both methods are overriden!? It iss till unclear for me...

Answer (score 1):

This is because a child class can only access a parent's method if it's `public` or `protected`, but not `private`. So it resorts to **its own** private method.

If you always want to call the current class' method, use `self::` instead of `$this->`.

Comment: hmmm....
operator self:: is a class operator that is used for constants and static members. It is still unclear to me, because i would expect to access both overriden methods in a subclass. It gets private from a superClass and public from a subClass. Maybe this is proper behaviour?? Who knows

Comment: `self::` can also be used for methods. Try it!

Comment: I was playing around a little and i think it is because the scope. Method which uses #this# in combination with a private #member# (function or property) and it is inherited it is still somekind treated as a member of a SUPERclass and cant access private members of SUBclasses! On the other hand it can access public and protected members. Because it can access private members of subclasses it still points to private members in a superclass... Something like that. If i use self:: always evelute to a superclass!